# Manipulating lists Python

Tags: python, list-manipulation

I have the following code:

```
import sys

A=['Anne','Romeo','Flynn','Mickey']
B=['Bravo','Whiskey','Anne','Flynn','Joe', 'Marianne']
C=['2', 'Joe', 'Marshall','2']
D=['Connor', '2', 'Robert', 'Marshall', 'George', 'Franklin']
E=['2', 'Flynn', '2', 'Richard', 'Phillip']
F=['Rex', 'Fer', 'Dan', 'Daniel', 'Didi', 'Didier']

for name in A:
        if name in B:
                match=name
                a_index = A.index(match)
                c_element = C[a_index]
                b_index = B.index(match)
                e_element = E[b_index]
                f_element = F[b_index]
                if c_element == e_element:
                       print([match, c_element, f_element])
```

But I get the following error:

```
e_element = E[b_index] 
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My output should be something like:

```
Anne     2       Dan
```

The algorithm should be something like this:

First common element between A and B is Anne => matches => let's check the elements from lists C and E from the same rows as list A and B => '2' is the correspondent for list C and '2' is the correspondent for list E => matches => open a new sheet in Excel => write common element between A and B(which is Anne, in our example) in Excel => write common element between C and E(which is 2, in our example) in col=2, row=1 => write the element from the same row as list B and E(row 7) from list F('Dan') in col=3, row=1.

For the moment, I wanted to show just on screen, but the main goal should be to insert this data into Excel and I would like that the script to be more scalable (to not apply just for this example since I have each list with at least 10k elements).

Any idea what is wrong in the code?

Many thanks in advance,

Dan

Comment: What are `view` and `viewsrv`?

Comment: Use a debugger and inspect `b_index` it is either bigger then `len(E)` or None - but I think None would give antoher error message ` list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType`

Comment: E only has 5 elements while B has 6. The index returned by `B.index` for Marianne will be out of bounds for E

Comment: You should handle these problems gracefully using a `try/except` block and specify `except IndexError` and determine what you want to do.

Comment: @pstatix: I have corrected that typo. Now the code reflects my last trying

Comment: When I [run](https://ideone.com/kWqYQJ) this program, I do not get any errors. I get `['Anne', 2, 'Dan']` two times as output.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, Panagiotis Kanavos: In my real example: list A has 15315 elements; list B - 41431 elements; list C - 15315 elements; list E - 15315 elements; list F - 28239 elements

Comment: @pstatix: Try/except block will give me just one entry always. I have tried something like: `try:
    match = [name for name in A if name in B][0]
except:
    print("No matches")
    sys.exit(1)

a_index = A.index(match)
c_element = C[a_index]
b_index = B.index(match)
e_element = E[b_index]
f_element = F[b_index]

if c_element == e_element:
    print([match, c_element, f_element])`

Comment: @dante Please update the post with what you have tried, not a comment. This is two difficult to read without proper syntax structure.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your code has incorrect indentation:

```
for name in A:
    if name in B:
        match=name
        a_index = A.index(match)
        c_element = C[a_index]
        b_index = B.index(match)
        e_element = E[b_index]
        f_element = F[b_index]
        if c_element == e_element:
            print([match, c_element, f_element])
```

Comment: @Carlos Fernández: For some reason, that part did not had proper indentation. The code was exactly like yours

Comment: @pstatix: For some reason, that part did not had proper indentation. The code was exactly like Carlos's

Comment: @dante Are you saying the issue is not resolved? If so, I cannot replicate.